# Requiring model schemas in another model for mongoose in different files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, mongoose

I am trying to require my model in a model. I am sure that my path for requiring is correct as there is no error in my require, but it seems like it is not triggering my model whenever I save a new instance. What am I missing here?

role.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var role = new Schema({
        type: String,
        level: Number,
    });

    role.pre("save",function(next) {
        this.type = 'member';
        this.level = 0;

        next();
    });

    return mongoose.model('Role', role);
}
```

user.js

```
module.exports = function (connection) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        Role = require('./role.js'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var user = new mongoose.Schema({
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        profile_image: String,
        company_name: String,
        type: [{ type : String, default: 'Local' }],
        created_at: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
        created_by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        role: [Role]
    });

    return connection.model('User', user);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get direct access of the underlying schema from a model instance as follows:

```
module.exports = function (connection) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Role = require('./role.js'),
        RoleSchema = mongoose.model('Role').schema,
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var user = new mongoose.Schema({
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        profile_image: String,
        company_name: String,
        type: [{ type : String, default: 'Local' }],
        created_at: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
        created_by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        role: [RoleSchema]
    });

    return mongoose.model('User', user);
}
```

Comment: I totally forgotten about using mongoose.model('Role').schema to access the Schema. Thanks! It works now.

Comment: How would be controller then for the `RoleSchema` ?
For example to store data and to show data ?